# How to do Pit Tests (Mutation tests) with Junit5 in InteliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5, mutation-testing, pittesting

I tried to set up Pit Tests in inteliJ-idea but unfortunately i am not sure how to set it up, in the end i did them in eclipse and it is much easier to navigate, but i would like to know how to set them up on inteliJ-idea. It is kinda stupid to change platform to do some tests, that is why I am asking this.

Comment: What did you do in Eclipse apart from configuring the build? In the end, if you have a working Gradle or Maven file it should work in both IDEs.

Comment: Does this plugin help https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7119-pit-mutation-testing-idea-plugin ?